# How do you use a member function inside a static function c++

Tags: c++

The callback function from an external C library takes

`void ds30_set_event_callback(void(*)(const ds30_event_t, const boolean, const void* const));`

I am able to output things to the console when it is called, but I am currently not able to compile the code. I am having a hard time with the sample problem below.

I am not able to pass a reference object to the callback, i cannot change the signature of the callback handler. How do i make the static function aware of a member function, or How do i make the static function aware of the class instance?

```
/*static*/ void FirmwareUi::ds30_event_handler(const ds30_event_t event, const boolean success, const void* const data)
    {
        if (event == DEBUG_INFO) 
        {
            auto text = data;       
            LPSTR output = LPSTR(text);     
            OutputDebugStringA(output);

            UpdateGui(output);
        }

    }//ds30_event_handler()

    void FirmwareUi::UpdateGui(LPCSTR data)
    {
        m_ctlDisplay->AppendText(data);
    }
```

The Error I'm getting is Error  C2352 FirmwareUi : illegal call of non-static member function

How should i approach this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951653/how-to-pass-a-member-function-as-a-parameter-portaudio

Comment: Unless you can set some kind of "user data pointer", then it's not really possible. You need a pointer to the `FirmwareUi` object.

Comment: Possibly simplest approach would be having a static pointer variable storing the ui instance to be used in the callback function. Of course you need to make sure the instance lives long enough that the pointer is yet valid any time the callback might get called – i. e. first unregister the callback, then delete the object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are correct. I ended up using a global variable that seems to work.

Comment: What is the `const void* const data` in the callback? Is that something you can set along with the callback? Any good callback has such a field for use of the user to pass data into the callback. In your case pass the `FirmwareUi` object, cast it to `FirmwareUi` and use that to call the method.

Comment: @GosWin von Brederlow Unfortunately, i cannot change that its from a library we bought.

Comment: Then you are stuck with a global. But since you bought the library why not ask their support to help? Good callbacks have a `void *user_data`.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez: approx. how many parallel callbacks are you preparing for?

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own user data structure that contains both the text and a reference to the class instance.
Within the callback you cast the input parameter to your structure and extract the text and instance.

Comment: Hm, the setter does not allow to pass a separate void pointer. *Might* mean that the data is generated together with the event and we might not have influence on type or content. If so, this approach is not applicable...

Comment: @rafael Could you provide the definition of the function that sets the callback?

Comment: It's there already, second line in Q, and the setter just accepts a function pointer...

Comment: That looks like the definition of the callback itself. I meant the setter of the callback. The one that wants your callback as one of its parameters.

Comment: From the question: `void ds30_set_event_callback(void(*)(const ds30_event_t, const boolean, const void* const));`

Comment: @Aconcagua you're right. I didn't read it well. Please forget my answer since it's not a possible solution. I won't delete it since it might add something useful anyway

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices in a case like this, assuming that `m_ctlDisplay`is a member function of FirmwareUi:

- You make UpdateGui a non-static member function. In that case, the `this` instance pointer that is implicitly passed to a regular member function (but not a static one) is available and the function has access to `m_ctlDisplay`.
- If it is not possible to convert `UpdateGui`to a regular, non-static member function, you'll need to extend the function signature and pass in a pointer to the `FirmwareGui` instance your code needs to refer to to get access to the `m_ctlDisplay` instance.

This is indicative of a class design issue inasmuch as it shows that `UpdateGui` really should have been/needs to be a non-static, instance member function rather than a static (class) member function.