# Using an intermediary function to direct a callback to a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, function-pointers, stdbind

I believe this question resembles this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951653/how-to-pass-a-member-function-as-a-parameter-portaudio). However I am not sure how to adjust that to my case. Here is what I am doing.

I currently have something like this

```
void IOCompletionCallback(_In_ DWORD dwErrorCode, _In_ DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
   ......    
}

void foo::Work()
{
     if (!BindIoCompletionCallback(hnd, IOCompletionCallback, 0))
     {
          printf("Error (error code: %u)\n", GetLastError());
     }
}
```

In the above code I am using the windows API `BindIoCompletionCallback` which takes in the function `IOCompletionCallback`. What I would like to do is to actually make `IOCompletionCallback` a method of foo instead of a free function so I could do this

```
if (!BindIoCompletionCallback(hnd, std::bind( &foo::IOCompletionCallback,this), 0))
{
}
```

but I read that is impossible because signature of the method takes in a specific type. From the link I posted that it states that you can use an intermediary method. I am not sure how Ill be able to pass the instance address to that intermediary method. Any suggestions on that approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code where you make the call for the IO to the question? i.e. the read or write call that the completion callback is used with?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that is somewhere later in the code. I am not sure i can modify that code. Can you tell me what you might be thinking ?

Comment: If you control the OVERLAPPED structure that is used, you can make that part of a class and cast the pointer (as is done [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-server-using-completion-routines) for a similar thing, but there are better ways in C++ to handle the casts than are shown in that C code).

Comment: YEah that makes sense. I wonder if I can use a lambda here instead of passing that function

Comment: @JamesFranco only a *non-capturing* lambda is convertible to a function pointer, and so can be used anywhere a free-function is expected.  A *capturing* lambda cannot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are correct. I just tested this.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm can you suggest how I can pass something to LPOVERLAPPED ? I would either like to add an index to it or an instance address. I think I have access to the OVERLAPPED structure

Comment: You could derive a class from OVERLAPPED, then cast the pointer from LPOVERLAPPED to a pointer to your class, or declare an OVERLAPPED member as the first the class, then pass a pointer to that member and convert it back in the callback (this is the approach used in the example I linked to).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

Use the lpoverlapped you create and pass in to the io operation to store the calllback.  Well, data before/after ithe OVERLAPPED..  This function should just cast the overlapped to the larger state, find the callback you stored there, and invoke that callback.

The callback can be a std function with all of its wonderful utility.

```
template<class D>
struct MyOverlapped:OVERLAPPED{
  std::function<void(DWORD, DWORD, D*)> callback;
  MyOverlapped():OVERLAPPED{0}{}
  virtual ~MyOverlapped() {}
};
```

Something sort of like this.  You'd use it like:

```
template<class D>
void MyIOCompletionCallback(_In_ DWORD dwErrorCode, _In_ DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
  if (!lpOverlapped) return;
  auto* pOverlapped = static_cast<D*>(lpOverlapped);
  pOverlapped->callback( dwErrorCode, dwNumberOfBytesTransferred, pOverlapped );
  delete pOverlapped; // as MyOverlapped
}

struct ReadFileOverlapped: MyOverlapped<ReadFileOverlapped> {
  explicit ReadFileOverlapped(std::size_t count = 0) {
    data.resize(count);
  }
  DWORD size() const { return static_cast<DWORD>(data.size()); }
  std::vector<std::byte> data;
};
auto overlapped = std::make_unique<ReadFileOverlapped>(1024);
overlapped->callback = [=](_In_ DWORD dwErrorCode, _In_ DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, ReadFileOverlapped* pOverlapped ) {
  std::cout << "Error " << dwErrorCode << "\n";
  std::cout << "Bytes " << dwNumberOfBytesTransfered << "\n";
  // get at data in pOverlapped->data.data() through pOverlapped->data.data()+dwNumberOfBytesTransfered or somesuch
};
if (ReadFile( hnd,
  overlapped->data.data(),
  overlapped->size(),
  nullptr,
  overlapped.get()
)) {
  if (BindIoCompletionCallback(hnd, MyIOCompletionCallback<ReadFileOverlapped>, 0))
  {
    overlapped.release();
  }
}
```